# Relation between probability measure of stochastic process and counting measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose that we observe a realisation $x$ of a stochastic process $X$, where $x$ is a $K\times 1$ vector taking value in $\{0,1\}^K$.

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the probability measure associated with the probability space where the stochastic process takes place. Without further assumptions, can we write down which is the relation between
$$
P \equiv \frac{\text{Number of components of $x$ equal to $1$}}{K}
$$
and $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: You are saying that $X$ is a random binary vector in $k$ dimensions.  $\mathbb{P}$ is a general probability measure.  Your quantity $P$ seems to be a random variable (a real-valued function of the random vector $X$).  So $\mathbb{P}$ and $P$ are different types of things, I don't think it is meaningful to "relate" the two.  Certainly the probability measure of $X$ can be used to deterine the distribution of $P$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand.

Comment: If $\{X_i\}$ is an iid sequence of binary random variables with $P[X_i=1]=p$, then it would make sense to relate the limiting fraction of time we get a 1 with $p$ (by the law of large numbers).

Comment: Yes, so a sufficient conditions to relate the two objects would be i.i.d. so that there is a LLN that I can apply. Got it.

Comment: You would be relating a marginal probability $Pr[X_1=1]$ to the limiting fraction of time seeing a 1.  Note that the joint probability is a different type of thing, it is $\mathbb{P}(x_1, ..., x_k) = Pr[X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2,...X_k=x_k]$, defined for all binary vectors $(x_1, ..., x_k)$, and for iid it reduces to $\prod_{i=1}^kPr[X_i=x_i]$.